# Google Calendar API in swift return recurrence = nil while return recurringEventId

Tags: ios, swift, google-api, google-calendar-api

When queryForEventsListWithCalendarId it return all events but repeated task return recurrence = nil and recurringEventId = id how to get recurrence rule to know if this event repeated daily, weekly or monthly

```
func fetchEvents(){

    let query = GTLQueryCalendar.queryForEventsListWithCalendarId("primary")
    query.maxResults = 30

    query.timeMin = NSDate()

    query.singleEvents = true
    query.orderBy = kGTLCalendarOrderByStartTime
    service.executeQuery(
        query,
        delegate: self,
        didFinishSelector: "displayResultWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:"
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the codes?

Comment: I added code to the question

Answer (score 2):

Finally i reached to the answer after trying all queries i found to get events with recurrence mode "Daily - Weekly - Monthly" i should use the following query

```
let query = GTLQueryCalendar.queryForEventsListWithCalendarId("primary")
```